# Unable to install guest additions in Ubuntu fresh VBox install

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, guest-additions

I have created a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10-desktop-i386 in virtualbox. Host is Windows 7. Virtualbox version is 3.2.8

I am trying to get the VBGuestAdditions to work, and I get errors

```
Building the main Guest Additions module... fail!
(Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong)
Installing the Windows System drivers
Warning: unknown version of the X Windows System installed, Not installing X Windows system drivers.
```

inside the suggested log file

```
ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing
Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it
```

I do not understand this but searching for the error in log file i found that things like running `apt-get install linux-source` would fix it... Unfortunately I get error

```
Unable to locate package linux-source
```

(which I fixed by going to a different repository)

At this point I don't know how to proceed with getting the Guest additions installed.

Comment: That version of VirtualBox is quite ancient. Is there a reason why you're using it? Btw you can install precompiled Guest Additions from an ISO bundled with VirtualBox.

Comment: It is what I will have to use for testing... I don't have a choice in the version, and neither am I able to load a different iso for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the `/etc/apt/sources.list` to use `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/`, then I was able to install all packages with `apt-get install`